# /app/translations defined in translator.paths

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Symfony 4 being deployed to GAE.
Everything deploys fine till I add

`composer require validator`

When I get this error on deployment:

```
Step #1:   - Installing symfony/validator (v4.0.9): Loading from cache
Step #1: Generating optimized autoload files
Step #1: ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
Step #1: ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Step #1: Executing script cache:clear [KO]
Step #1:  [KO]
Step #1: Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
Step #1: !!  
Step #1: !!  In FrameworkExtension.php line 916:
Step #1: !!                                                                                 
Step #1: !!    /app/translations defined in translator.paths does not exist or is not a di  
Step #1: !!    rectory                                                                      
Step #1: !!                                                                                 
Step #1: !!  
Step #1: !!  
Step #1: Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c /build-scripts/composer.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
```

Any ideas on a setting I need? Have spent two days working and searching and nothing. TIA

Comment: I should add that composer require validator also adds symfony/translation

Comment: Is there /app/translations directory?

Comment: Also, check the permissions on project folders.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
app/translations exists with drwxrwxr-x